# How to write chef spec for following cookbook?

Tags: ruby, rspec, chefspec

This is my recipe.rb:

```
require 'mixlib/shellout'
require "pry"

find = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("echo hostname -I")
find.run_command.stdout
```

What should I write it in my spec?

Comment: What do you want the spec to test? That a certain command has been executed? That a certain thing has been printed to STDOUT? Btw, I'm not sure this is doing what you expect... It's literally printing the string `"hostname -I"`; it's not actually running the `hostname` command. I don't think you mean to write `echo` there.

Comment: I want to run this command and display stdout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the echo command to get the output. you can directly run the command through [`mixlib/shellout`](https://github.com/chef/mixlib-shellout) and get then get the command output from `stdout`.

```rb
require 'mixlib/shellout'

find = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("hostname -I")
find.run_command.stdout
```